# Converting CGAL Nef_polyhedron_3 cube to Polyhedron_3

Tags: cgal

I'm trying to create a simple NEF cube from planes and get its vertices. Unfortunately, I am not getting any facets.

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_3<Kernel> Nef_polyhedron;
typedef Nef_polyhedron::Plane_3 Plane_3;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel> Polyhedron;

// As in https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Nef_3/Nef_3_2point_set_operations_8cpp-example.html
Nef_polyhedron N1(Plane_3(1, 0, 0, -1));
Nef_polyhedron N2(Plane_3(-1, 0, 0, -1));
Nef_polyhedron N3(Plane_3(0, 1, 0, -1));
Nef_polyhedron N4(Plane_3(0, -1, 0, -1));
Nef_polyhedron N5(Plane_3(0, 0, 1, -1));
Nef_polyhedron N6(Plane_3(0, 0, -1, -1));
Nef_polyhedron cube = N1 * N2 * N3 * N4 * N5 * N6;

// Loading a cube from file works:
// std::ifstream file("cube.off");
// assert(file);
// Polyhedron p2;
// file >> p2;
// Nef_polyhedron cube(p2);

Polyhedron p;
assert(cube.is_simple());
cube.convert_to_polyhedron(p);
assert(p.facets_begin() != p.facets_end());   // asserts
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need an extended kernel to handle halfspace. When you run the program you see this message `Constructor not available for this Kernel
`.  See the Kernel used in the example you refer. Note if you don't need to handle infinite, no need to use such a Kernel.

Comment: Thank you sloriot! I hadn't seen that message because console output ends up nowhere in Windows GUI applications. I see, it didn't work because I used unbounded halfspaces (planes) to create the cube. If anybody else stumbles upon this, this is actually documented here https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Nef_3/index.html#sectionNef_3InfiBox. I found it after you pointed me in the right direction.